# Fast double sum involving Kronecker symbol

Tags: performance-tuning, summation

I have three lists
$$A=\{\alpha_1...\alpha_N\}$$
$$B=\{\beta_1...\beta_N\}$$
$$M=\{M_1....M_N\}$$

In practice $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ are complex numbers with modulus smaller than 1. The $M_i$s are integers in between -6 and 6.

I want to compute the following sum:

$$S=2\sum_i\sum_j\alpha_i\beta_j\delta_{M^i,M^j}$$

My best attempt is basically

```
ComputeSum[A_, B_,M_] := 
 Block[{kroneckerList},
  k= Outer[KroneckerDelta, M, M];
  ak= A*kroneckerList;
  Total[ak.B]
  ]
```

Which I believe does the job (but in any case what I want to compute is the sum above).
The problem is that $N$ can be quite big, up to $3\times 10^6$.
and the `k= Outer[KroneckerDelta, M, M]` line gets computationally expensive.

Do you have faster solutions ?

Comment: Have you tried using simply `Sum[..., {i, n}, {j, n}]`?

Comment: yes, that's a very bad way of doing it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
ComputeSum[A_, B_, M_] := A . Outer[KroneckerDelta, M, M] . B;

(*A helper function that for additive assembly of `SparseArray`s (_Mathematica's_ default is first in, last out.) *)
Options[MySparseArray] = {"Background" -> 0.};
MySparseArray[X_, r_, f_ : Total] := 
  If[(Head[X] === Rule) && (X[[1]] === {}),
   X[[2]],
   With[{spopt = SystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions"]},
    Internal`WithLocalSettings[
     SetSystemOptions[
      "SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> f}],
     SparseArray[X, r, OptionValue["Background"]],
     SetSystemOptions[spopt]]
    ]
   ];

ComputeSum2[A_, B_, M_, k_] := Dot[
   MySparseArray[Partition[M + k + 1, 1] -> A, {2 k + 1}],
   MySparseArray[Partition[M + k + 1, 1] -> B, {2 k + 1}]
   ];

ComputeSum3[A_, B_, M_] := Dot[
   Values[GroupBy[Transpose[{M, A}], First -> Last, Total]],
   Values[GroupBy[Transpose[{M, B}], First -> Last, Total]]
   ];


n = 10000;
A = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, n];
B = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, n];
k = 6;
M = RandomInteger[{-k, k}, n];

result = ComputeSum[A, B, M]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
result2 = ComputeSum2[A, B, M, k]; // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First
result3 = ComputeSum3[A, B, M]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
Abs[result - result2]
Abs[result - result3]
Abs[result - result3]
```

> 16.8646
>
> 0.002846
>
> 0.006937
>
> 2.27374*10^-12
>
> 9.09495*10^-13

**Edit**

The idea of the two implementations is the same. We want to compute
$$\begin{aligned}
   \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_i \, \delta_{M_i,M_j} \, \beta_j 
   &= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=-6}^6 \alpha_i \, \delta_{M_i,k} \, \delta_{k,M_j} \, \beta_j 
   \\
   &= \sum_{k=-6}^6  \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i \, \delta_{M_i,k} \right) \, \left(  \sum_{j=1}^n  \delta_{k,M_j} \, \beta_j \right)   
   \\
   & = u^T v,
\end{aligned}$$
where
$$
   u_k = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \, \delta_{M_i,k}
   \qquad
   v_k = \sum_{j=1}^n \beta_j \, \delta_{M_j,k}.
$$
The naive summation costs $O(n^2)$; but each of `u` and `v` can be computed in $O((2\,k +1) \, n)$ time. So the new algorithm has complexity
$$
O(2\,(2\,k +1) \,n + (2\,k +1)) = O(2\,(2\,k +1)\,n).
$$
So if the range of `k` is much smaller than `n`, then we can save quite many flops this way.

Hence we may use

```
MySparseArray[Partition[M + k + 1, 1] -> A, {2 k + 1}]
```

(where we have to add shift the integers in `M` to be all greater than `0`) or

```
Values[GroupBy[Transpose[{M, A}], First -> Last, Total]]
```

to assemble the vector `u`. Likewise we can do it for `v`. And in the end we just have `Dot` `u` and `v` together to get the result.

Comment: It's always you @Henrik Schumacher, thanks. This is some next level mathematica programming. Do you have a blog or an online class where you teach this kind of technique ? Because I know it works but I don't understand most your syntax

Comment: No online material other than what I post here on StackExchange. But I added the mathematical explaination of why it works. I hope it helps.

Comment: I now have to compute a sum that looks like this @Henrik Schumacher :
$S=2\sum_i\sum_j\alpha_i\beta_j\delta_{M^i,M^j}\delta_{M'_i,M'_j}$,   where $M'=\{M'_1....M'_N\}$. My code looks like this, where I use the idea of your answer without the first aprt which I don't understand very well.  Can I do much better you think ?

Comment: Test[A_, B_, M_, M1_] := Block[{kT, kT1},
  kT = ParallelTable[
    SparseArray[CustomKroneker[#, k] & /@ M], {k, -6, 6}];
  kT1 = ParallelTable[
    SparseArray[CustomKroneker[#, k] & /@ M1], {k, -6, 6}];
  AbsoluteTiming[Sum[Sum[
     Total[A*kT[[k + 7]]*kT1[[p + 7]]]*
      Total[B*(kT[[k + 7]])*(kT1[[p + 7]])]
     , {k, -6, 6}], {p, -6, 6}]]
  ]

Comment: CustomKroneker[M_, ms_] := 
  CustomKroneker[M, ms] = KroneckerDelta[M, ms];

Comment: Well, $\delta_{M_i,M_j} \, \delta_{M'_i,M'_j} = \delta_{(M_i,M'_i),(M_j,M'_j)}$, so you can simply use `ComputeSum3[A, B, Transpose[{M, M1}]]`. The `SparseArray` thing would work, too, if appropriately adapted. I think it's `Module[{numberOfPairs, knew, Mnew},
 numberOfPairs = (2 k + 1)^2;
 knew = (numberOfPairs - 1)/2;
 Mnew = (2 k + 1) (M + k) + M1 + k - knew;
 ComputeSum2[A, B, Mnew, knew]
 ]`.

Comment: The idea behind the `SparseArray` trick here is to convert the pairs $(M_i,M'_i)$ into  a single integer by treating $M_i+k+1$ and $M'_i + k + 1$ as digits of numbers with base $2 k +1$.